# Selecting CDI bean by annotation with table of arguments

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

How to choose CDI java bean base on annotation, then the annotation poses table of arguments?

The problem is easier to show using an example than to describe.

Assume that for each object of type **Problem** we have to choose proper solution.

```
public class Problem {

    private Object data;
    private ProblemType type;

    public Object getData() { return data; }
    public void setData(Object data) { this.data = data; }
    public ProblemType getType() { return type; }
    public void setType(ProblemType type) { this.type = type;}
}
```

There are few types of problems:

```
public enum ProblemType {
    A, B, C;
}
```

There are few solutions:

```
public interface Solution {
    public void resolve(Problem problem);
}
```

like **FirstSolution**:

```
@RequestScoped
@SolutionQualifier(problemTypes = { ProblemType.A, ProblemType.C })
public class FirstSolution implements Solution {

    @Override
    public void resolve(Problem problem) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and **SecondSolution**:

```
@RequestScoped
@SolutionQualifier(problemTypes = { ProblemType.B })
public class SecondSolution implements Solution {

    @Override
    public void resolve(Problem problem) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The solution should be chosen based on annotation **@SolutionQualifier**:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface SolutionQualifier {

    ProblemType[] problemTypes();

    public static class SolutionQualifierLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<SolutionQualifier> implements SolutionQualifier {

        private ProblemType[] problemTypes;

        public SolutionQualifierLiteral(ProblemType[] problems) {
            this.problemTypes = problems;
        }

        @Override
        public ProblemType[] problemTypes() {
            return problemTypes;
        }
    }
}
```

By **SolutionProvider**:

```
@RequestScoped
public class DefaultSolutionProvider implements SolutionProvider {

    @Inject
    @Any
    private Instance<Solution> solutions;

    @Override
    public Instance<Solution> getSolution(Problem problem) {

        /**
         * Here is the problem of choosing proper solution.
         * I do not know how method {@link javax.enterprise.inject.Instance#select(Annotation...)}
         * works, and how it compares annotations, so I do no know what argument I should put there
         * to obtain proper solution.
         */

        ProblemType[] problemTypes = { problem.getType() };
        return solutions.select(new SolutionQualifier.SolutionQualifierLiteral(problemTypes));
    }
}
```

And in the last one there is a problem:
I do not know how method **javax.enterprise.inject.Instance#select(Annotation...)** works internally, and how it compares annotations, so I do no know what argument I should put there to obtain proper solution. If there appear a problem of type **A** table **ProblemType[]** will consist of one argument, while **FirstSolution.class** is annotated with **@SolutionQualifier** having two arguments, so therefore I will not get the proper Instance.

Comment: The CDI spec v2.0 specifies repeating qualifiers, see section 2.3.6. It might suit you, if you are in CDI 2.

Comment: `AnnotationLiteral` matches on the field values and annotationType. In this case, an equality in `problemTypes`. Generally, CDI discourages using `Arrays` for qualifier fields, unless they are marked `@NonBinding`. Anyhow, to solve the problem, you can override `equals()` of the `AnnotationLiteral` and rather than `equality` check, you perform your own `containedIn` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to resolve it using CDI API, instead:

I created another enum:

```
public enum SoultionType {
    A(ProblemType.A, ProblemType.C), 
    B(ProblemType.A);

    //...

    SoultionType(ProblemType problems...) {
        // ...
    }

    public static SoultionType getByProblemType(ProblemType problem) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Changed so SolutionQualifier has only SoultionType field inside, so there is no problem with the comparison.